# DHCP Server not working on PI

Tags: wifi, dhcp

I have followed the instruction how to make my pi a webserver: 
https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/

Everything is working fine expect that the Pi is not acting like a dhcp server. If I try to connect over wifi I am not getting a ip Adress.

Is there a way I can test if the dhcp configs are wrong or not working? I have followed all the steps in the tutorial.

Comment: If you set a static IP on the device you're connecting to the Pi, does everything work OK?

Comment: Have you paid attention to the last 4 comments from march 2018 at the linked tutorial? This tutorial seems to be outdated and not working!

Comment: Can you tell if `dnsmasq` is running?  That is the DHCP server for the WiFi.  Do you see any log entries in `/var/log/syslog` for dnsmasq?  Or anything else interesting?

Comment: i can see if it is running whith sudo systemctl status dnsmasq
 however it is not doing enything...

Comment: Can you post your configuration files and syslog so we can check if there are any typos?  Checkout this [blog posting](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=164134) to see what files to check and what syslog entries to look for.  You should reboot to get a fresh syslog showing dnsmasq startup log entries.

Comment: actually i removed everything from the tutorial and used another tutorial that has not bridging.

Comment: That's a good point, because if you bridge the two networks together, then the DHCP server on the Ethernet LAN should respond to the DHCP request.  I use a Raspberry Pi 2 using `hostapd` and route between the WLAN and LAN.  My setup uses `udhcpd`